# Bootstrap 4 nav-pills - how to set inactive pills to use outline

Tags: bootstrap-4, outline, nav-pills

I want the inactive pills in my Bootstrap 4 'nav' to have the 'btn-outline-primary' class instead of just being plain text without a border. How?

example from the Bootstrap 4 docs...

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="pills-tabContent">
  <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="pills-home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-home-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-profile-tab">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="pills-contact-tab">...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the classes `border`, `border-primary` and `rounded` to your `li`, in order to get the same styling as `btn-outline-primary`.

So, replace:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills mb-3" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
  <li class="nav-item border border-primary rounded">
    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-home-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-home" role="tab"
      aria-controls="pills-home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item border border-primary rounded">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-profile-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-profile" role="tab"
      aria-controls="pills-profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item border border-primary rounded">
    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-contact-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-contact" role="tab"
      aria-controls="pills-contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly!  I also changed "rounded" to "rounded-pill" to make the tabs look like 'chips'.